# OWIN shuts down immediately after startup

Tags: asp.net, owin

After a lot of trial and error, In order to find the cause, I have reduced the startup to this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        RegisterOnShutdown(app);
        Log.Debug("\n   Startup end !!!");
    }

    private void RegisterOnShutdown(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var context = new OwinContext(app.Properties);
        var token = context.Get<CancellationToken>("host.OnAppDisposing");
        if (token != CancellationToken.None)
        {
            token.Register(OnShutdown);
        }
    }

    private void OnShutdown()
    {
        Log.Debug("\n   Shutdown !!!");
    }
}
```

And I get this log:

```
2022-12-11 08:00:27,045 [1] DEBUG (null) Web.Startup [(null)] <(null)> - 
   Startup end !!!
2022-12-11 08:00:29,751 [7] DEBUG (null) Web.Startup [(null)] <(null)> - 
   Shutdown !!!
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file was put in the bin folder, which shouldn't have been, as it changes and causes change to the folder. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.shutdownreason)

Relocating the file solved the problem.